# Log user provided input values and the fucntions called while execution of GUI

Tags: python, logging

I have made a GUI using tkinter in python. Now i want to prepare a log file, which should be able to capture all the events which are executed by the user i.e if the user is giving some input value to a function, the log file should be able to capture that input value and the corresponding function where the value was given as input.

Basically if someone wants to see what operations where performed by user, they should be able to get it through the log file.
I came across "trace" module in python, but it traces program execution flow. I want the operations performed in the GUI to be captured.

Any idea will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `logging` module already? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: @angelogro, yes to begin with i looked into the logging module. But i was not getting the idea how to capture user input values into the log file using logging module. I want a traceback kind of functionality where i am able to see which functions were called during one run of the GUI. Thanks !!!

Comment: Can you maybe provide a minimal example and the desired output to the log file?

Comment: @angelogro, Thanks for the information. I made custom statements whenever button is clicked and passed it to my logging module as INFO. I figured it out i guess. Thanks again